# java 7 Handling multiple exceptions in a single catch block

Tags: java-7

I am not getting any satisfactory answer about how to maintain exception hierarchy while **handling multiple exception in single catch block** in java 7. I am describing some scenario in below.

**Scen - 1:**

```
 try
    {
      Class.forName("abc");
    }  
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);    
    }
```

In above scenario is working fine. Come to 2nd scenario.

**Scen - 2:**

```
 try
    {
      Class.forName("abc");
    }  
    catch(ReflectiveOperationException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);    
    }
```

In above scenario is working fine because ReflectiveOperationException is the super class of **ClassNotFoundException** . Come to 3rd scenario.

**Scen - 3:**

```
try
{
  Class.forName("abc");
}  
catch(Exception e)
{
  System.out.println(e);    
}
```

In above scenario it is showing compile time error. I am not understanding why it is showing error. As **Exception** is the super class of **ClassNotFoundException** , it should not show any error. again come to 4th scenario.

**Scen - 4:**

```
 try
    {
      Class.forName("abc");
    }  
    catch(Throwable e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);    
    }
```

In above scenario it is working fine.

**Could anyone please explain about the above scenario?
Another thing is that I want to use all(ClassNotFoundException , ReflectiveOperationException ,Exception , Throwable ) above exception in single catch block as per java 7. How to use it?**

Comment: Please show us the complete compile-time error. In addition, please show us your import statements for the various exceptions, particularly the one for 'Exception e'. Let's make sure you are actually looking at the exception types you believe you are.

Comment: I guess, because you named one of your classes `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

It must compile fine in all the 4 scenarios. I tried it myself and all scenarios are fine. 
Coming to your second question, you can't use all the 4 exceptions in a single catch block as they are all related through parent-child relation (Throwable is parent of Exception, Exception is parent of ReflectiveOperationException, and ReflectiveOperationException is parent of ClassNotFoundException). On trying to use all 4 in single catch block, you will get a compilation error `The exception <any_child_exception> is already caught by the alternative <its_parent_exception>`.